# Can't mount Samba share - "No such device or address"

Tags: linux, mount, network-shares, samba

I have a WiFi modem (`10.1.1.1`) running a Samba 1.0 file server (`SHARE`) and a USB flash drive connected to it. I am trying to mount the share directory to my existing local directory `/mnt/smb`.

**Output of `smbclient -L //10.1.1.1 -U admin`:**

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
SanDisk_SandiskUltra_1_fe6f Disk      
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Home Network Gateway)
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

Server               Comment
---------            -------           
SHARE                Home Network Gateway

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            SHARE
```

**Output of `sudo mount -t cifs //10.1.1.1/SHARE /mnt/smb -o username=admin,vers=1.0`**

```
Password for admin@//10.1.1.1/SHARE: 
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I think it is strange that I get `No such device or address` when clearly the location of the share directory is `10.1.1.1/SHARE` as confirmed by `smbclient`.

I am not sure what else I can do from here--any ideas?